# Model for web applications

Tags: python, object-oriented, database, redis

I'm developing a model for web applications. The database that I use is Redis.

I created special `DbField` objects like `HashDbField`, `SortedSetDbField`, `ScalarDbField` and so on, for each data type in Redis. This objects provides a convenient way to work with redis keys. Each of it takes target key name in constructor

The second type of objects are `DbObject`s that represents objects in database. `DbObject`s (`UserDbObject`, `PostDbObject`) consist of `DbField`s.  There are class fields, for some global registers and instance fields for values of certain objects.

Each `dbObject` has a `DbObjectName` class field which contains the current object name ('user', 'post', 'comment', and so on...)

`DbObject` class looks like:

```
class DbObjectType(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        super(DbObjectType, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)
        cls._TypeInit()


class DbObject(metaclass=DbObjectType):
    DbObjectName = DB_OBJECT_NAME

    @classmethod
    def _TypeInit(cls):
        cls._SelfDbObjectSerializator = DbObjectSerializator(cls)

        cls.LastId = ScalarDbField(cls.DbObjectName, None, R_LAST_ID)

        cls.Reg = SortedSetDbField(cls.DbObjectName, None, R_REG, cls._SelfDbObjectSerializator, DateTimeSerializator)
        cls._Reg_raw = SortedSetDbField(cls.DbObjectName, None, R_REG)


    @classmethod
    def Create(cls):
        newDbObjectId = cls.LastId.increment()

        dbObject = cls(newDbObjectId)
        dbObject.createDate.set(datetime.now())

        return dbObject

    @classmethod
    def Get(cls, dbObjectId):
        assert dbObjectId

        if not cls._Reg_raw.contains(dbObjectId): return None

        return cls(dbObjectId)


    def delete(self):
        for value in self.__dict__.values():
            if isinstance(value, DbField):
                dbField = value
                dbField.destroy()


    def __init__(self, dbObjectId):
        assert dbObjectId

        self._dbObjectId = str(dbObjectId)

        self.createDate = ScoreDbField(self.DbObjectName, self._dbObjectId, F_CREATE_DATE, self.Reg, self, DateTimeSerializator)
        self.tag = ScalarDbField(self.DbObjectName, self._dbObjectId, F_TAG)


    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self._dbObjectId)

    def __str__(self):
        return self._dbObjectId

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if type(self) != type(other): return False
        return (self.DbObjectName == other.DbObjectName) and (self._dbObjectId == other._dbObjectId)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

    id = property(lambda self: self._dbObjectId)
```

As you can see, class fields defining in `TypeInit`, which is called right after class creates. This trick provides inheritance support, so `DbObject`'s derivative classes will contain `LastId` and `Reg` but for its own `DbObjectName`.

Is there way to make this more pythonic? I think this can be implemented with decorators, but I'm not sure it will be better.

Here are some `DbField`s:

```
class DbField():
    _Redis = None

    @classmethod
    def Connect(cls, host=None, port=None):
        cls._Redis = Redis(host or 'localhost', port or 6379, decode_responses =True)

    def __init__(self, dbObjectName, dbObjectId, fieldName, valueSerializator=None):
        assert dbObjectName
        assert fieldName

        self._dbObjectName = dbObjectName
        self._dbObjectId = dbObjectId
        self._fieldName = fieldName

        if self._dbObjectId:
            self._key = "%s:%s:%s" % (self._dbObjectName, self._dbObjectId, self._fieldName)
        else:
            self._key = "%s:%s" % (self._dbObjectName, self._fieldName)

        self._valueSerializator = valueSerializator or Serializator

    def exists(self):
        return self._Redis.exists(self._key)

    def destroy(self):
        return self._Redis.delete(self._key)


class HashDbField(DbField):
    def __init__(self, dbObjectName, dbObjectId, fieldName, valueSerializator=None, nameSerializator=None):
        super(HashDbField, self).__init__(dbObjectName, dbObjectId, fieldName, valueSerializator)

        self._nameSerializator = nameSerializator or Serializator

    def set(self, name, value, overwrite=True):
        return (self._Redis.hset if overwrite else self._Redis.hsetnx)(
            self._key, self._nameSerializator.serialize(name), self._valueSerializator.serialize(value)
        )

    def get(self, name):
        return self._valueSerializator.restore(
            self._Redis.hget(self._key, self._nameSerializator.serialize(name))
        )

    def delete(self, name):
        return self._Redis.hdel(self._key, self._nameSerializator.serialize(name))


class SortedSetDbField(DbField):
    def __init__(self, dbObjectName, dbObjectId, fieldName, valueSerializator=None, scoreSerializator=None):
        super(SortedSetDbField, self).__init__(dbObjectName, dbObjectId, fieldName, valueSerializator)

        self._scoreSerializator = scoreSerializator or Serializator

    def add(self, value, score):
        self._Redis.zadd(self._key, self._valueSerializator.serialize(value), self._scoreSerializator.serialize(score))

    def getRange(self, start=0, end=-1, desc=False):
        return map(self._valueSerializator.restore, self._Redis.zrange(self._key, start=start, end=end, desc=desc))

    def getScore(self, value):
        return self._scoreSerializator.restore(self._Redis.zscore(self._key, self._valueSerializator.serialize(value)))

    def setScore(self, value, score):
        self.add(value, score)

    def indexOf(self, value):
        return self._Redis.zrank(self._key, self._valueSerializator.serialize(value))

    def contains(self, value):
        return self.indexOf(value) is not None

    def delete(self, value):
        self._Redis.zrem(self._key, self._valueSerializator.serialize(value))

    def count(self):
        return self._Redis.zcard(self._key)

    def union(self, sortedSetDbField):
        assert isinstance(sortedSetDbField, SortedSetDbField)

        self._Redis.zunionstore(self._key, (self._key, sortedSetDbField._key), aggregate='max')

    def subtract(self, sortedSetDbField):
        assert isinstance(sortedSetDbField, SortedSetDbField)

        self._Redis.zunionstore(self._key, {self._key: 1, sortedSetDbField._key: -1}, aggregate='min')
        self._Redis.zremrangebyscore(self._key, '-inf', 0)



class ScalarDbField(DbField):
    def set(self, value, overwrite=True):
        return (self._Redis.set if overwrite else self._Redis.setnx)(self._key, self._valueSerializator.serialize(value))

    def get(self):
        return self._valueSerializator.restore(self._Redis.get(self._key))

    def increment(self, amount=1):
        return self._Redis.incr(self._key, amount)


class RefValueDbField(ScalarDbField):
    def __init__(self, dbObjectName, dbObjectId, fieldName, targetHashDbField, targetHashDbFieldValue, valueSerializator=None):
        super(RefValueDbField, self).__init__(dbObjectName, dbObjectId, fieldName, valueSerializator)

        self._targetHashDbField = targetHashDbField
        self._targetHashDbFieldValue = targetHashDbFieldValue

    def set(self, name, overwrite=False):
        if not self._targetHashDbField.set(name, self._targetHashDbFieldValue, overwrite):
            return False

        oldName = self.get()
        super(RefValueDbField, self).set(name)

        if oldName is not None: self._targetHashDbField.delete(oldName)

        return True

    def destroy(self):
        name = self.get()
        if name is not None: self._targetHashDbField.delete(name)

        super(RefValueDbField, self).destroy()


class ScoreDbField(ScalarDbField):
    def __init__(self, dbObjectName, dbObjectId, fieldName, targetSortedSetDbField, targetSortedSetDbFieldValue, valueSerializator=None):
        assert isinstance(targetSortedSetDbField, SortedSetDbField)

        super(ScoreDbField, self).__init__(dbObjectName, dbObjectId, fieldName, valueSerializator)
        self._targetSortedSetDbField = targetSortedSetDbField
        self._targetSortedSetDbFieldValue = targetSortedSetDbFieldValue

    def set(self, score):
        self._targetSortedSetDbField.setScore(self._targetSortedSetDbFieldValue, score)
        super(ScoreDbField, self).set(score)

    def exists(self):
        return self._targetSortedSetDbField.contains(self._targetSortedSetDbFieldValue)

    def destroy(self):
        self._targetSortedSetDbField.delete(self._targetSortedSetDbFieldValue)
        super(ScoreDbField, self).destroy()
```

I'm in trouble with `ScalarDbField` because I have to call get/set methods to get/set values.  I can't use it like descriptor to get/set values like in regular variable because it mostly used like instance field, and I don't like to use properties with lambdas:

```
nick = property(lambda self: self._nick.get(), lambda self, value: self._nick.set(value))
```

Here is `UserDbObject`:

```
class UserDbObject(DbObject):
    DbObjectName = DB_OBJECT_NAME

    @classmethod
    def _TypeInit(cls):
        super(cls, cls)._TypeInit()

        cls.Nicks = HashDbField(cls.DbObjectName, None, R_NICKS, cls._SelfDbObjectSerializator, nameSerializator=IgnoreCaseSerializator)
        cls.Emails = HashDbField(cls.DbObjectName, None, R_EMAILS, cls._SelfDbObjectSerializator, nameSerializator=IgnoreCaseSerializator)
        cls.AuthKeys = HashDbField(cls.DbObjectName, None, R_AUTH_KEYS, cls._SelfDbObjectSerializator)

        cls.LastLoginDates = SortedSetDbField(cls.DbObjectName, None, R_LAST_LOGIN_DATES, cls._SelfDbObjectSerializator, DateTimeSerializator)
        cls.LastActiveDates = SortedSetDbField(cls.DbObjectName, None, R_LAST_ACTIVE_DATES, cls._SelfDbObjectSerializator, DateTimeSerializator)

    @classmethod
    def Create(cls, nick, email, password, name, surname):
        assert nick
        assert email
        assert password

        userDbObject = super(UserDbObject, cls).Create()

        def setRefFields():
            if not userDbObject.nick.set(nick): return False
            if not userDbObject.email.set(email): return False
            return True

        if not setRefFields():
            userDbObject.delete()
            return None

        userDbObject.generateNewAuthKey()
        userDbObject.setPassword(password)

        if name: userDbObject.name.set(name)
        if surname: userDbObject.surname.set(surname)

        return userDbObject

    @classmethod
    def Get(cls, dbObjectId=None, nick=None, email=None, authKey=None):
        if dbObjectId:
            return super(UserDbObject, cls).Get(dbObjectId)

        if nick:
            return cls.Nicks.get(nick)

        if email:
            return cls.Emails.get(email)

        if authKey:
            return cls.AuthKeys.get(authKey)

        return None


    def setPassword(self, password):
        salt = generateRandomKey(SALT_LENGTH)
        self._passwordHash.set(countCoolHash(password, salt))
        self._salt.set(salt)

    def checkPassword(self, password):
        return self._passwordHash.get() == countCoolHash(password, self._salt.get())

    def generateNewAuthKey(self):
        while True:
            if self.authKey.set(generateRandomKey(AUTH_KEY_LENGTH)): break

    def __init__(self, dbObjectId):
        super(UserDbObject, self).__init__(dbObjectId)

        self.nick = RefValueDbField(self.DbObjectName, self._dbObjectId, F_NICK, self.Nicks, self)
        self.email = RefValueDbField(self.DbObjectName, self._dbObjectId, F_EMAIL, self.Emails, self)
        self.authKey = RefValueDbField(self.DbObjectName, self._dbObjectId, F_AUTH_KEY, self.AuthKeys, self)

        self._passwordHash = ScalarDbField(self.DbObjectName, self._dbObjectId, F_PASSWORD_HASH)
        self._salt = ScalarDbField(self.DbObjectName, self._dbObjectId, F_SALT)

        self.name = ScalarDbField(self.DbObjectName, self._dbObjectId, F_NAME)
        self.surname = ScalarDbField(self.DbObjectName, self._dbObjectId, F_SURNAME)

        self.lastLoginDate = ScoreDbField(self.DbObjectName, self._dbObjectId, F_LAST_LOGIN_DATE, self.LastLoginDates, self, DateTimeSerializator)
        self.lastActiveDate = ScoreDbField(self.DbObjectName, self._dbObjectId, F_LAST_ACTIVE_DATE, self.LastActiveDates, self, DateTimeSerializator)

        self.posts = SortedSetDbField(self.DbObjectName, self._dbObjectId, F_POSTS, self._PostDbObjectSerializator, DateTimeSerializator)

        self.followers = SortedSetDbField(self.DbObjectName, self._dbObjectId, F_FOLLOWERS, self._UserDbObjectSerializator, DateTimeSerializator)
        self.followingUsers = SortedSetDbField(self.DbObjectName, self._dbObjectId, F_FOLLOWING_USERS, self._UserDbObjectSerializator, DateTimeSerializator)

        self.feed = SortedSetDbField(self.DbObjectName, self._dbObjectId, F_FEED, self._PostDbObjectSerializator, DateTimeSerializator)
```

How can you help me improve this code?

Comment: While we're on the topic of being as pythonic as possible, [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends lowercase function names with underscores. So `SortedSetDbField.get_score` and `UserDbObject.create`.

Answer (score 3):

Woah, that's a lot of code.

In Python 3, you can do replace `super(DbObjectType, cls)` by `super()`.

Instead of

```
if not cls._Reg_raw.contains(dbObjectId): return None

return cls(dbObjectId)
```

You could do that

```
if cls._Reg_raw.contains(dbObjectId):
    return cls(dbObjectId)
```

Because Python automatically return None if nothing is returned.
(Or `return None` can be changed to `return` but it's not important)

Instead of using old %-formatting style for strings, you should start using `str.format` which is preferred since 2.6, like I stated it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587560/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-int-and-str/9588046#9588046).

Comparing types is bad so this `if type(self) != type(other):` is bad.
*At least* you should do `if not isinstance(self, type(other)):` or something along these lines.

Just FYI (just in case you or someone else didn't know), `property` can be used as a decorator too: [property in Python doc](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) .

Also check [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for proper naming conventions (how you should name your variables, methods, etc) as raylu said in comment of your question.

I must admit I didn't really analyze how your code works or what does it do: TL;DR.
I just looked for some piece of code I know could have some minor amelioration to make it more Pythonic.

And I don't know Redis.